# How can I assign an ID to a view created with a non-static method?

Tags: android

i used MyView.setId(View.generateViewId()); and i got "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method" error.

How i can solve it? To check MyView please follow this [link](https://github.com/valerio-bozzolan/AcrylicPaint/blob/master/src/anupam/acrylic/EasyPaint.java).
thank you!

Comment: @Mike M.  Yes,Exacly!

Answer (score 0):

MyView is the name of your class, so you can't call a non-static method such as setId() on it. You need to call it on a specific instance of the class, e.g:

```
MyView view = new MyView(this);
int id = View.generateViewId();
view.setId(id);
```

Alternatively you can call it from inside a method or the constructor of the MyView class, e.g:

```
setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Comment: so what's would be the id like? I didn't find it in R.java

Comment: It's the value returned by generateViewId(). You can save it to a variable (id in the above example). Or you can look it up by calling getId() on the view.

Comment: I got a waring "The static method generateViewId() from the type View should be accessed in a static way"  and a crash.. i used getActionBar().hide(); but it's appears on screenshot, i guess it's still visible in view.. anyway thank you for your help man!

Comment: Make sure you call View.generateViewId() and not view.generateViewId(). generateViewId() is a static method of the View class.

Comment: this is the code i used,no waring ,but it's crashs:    MyView view = new MyView(this);
  int vid = View.generateViewId();
  view.setId(vid);
  View vv = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
  View v = vv.findViewById(vid);

Comment: @Mike M. i took direcly the mBitmap, but the background is black, how i can take the canvas as background?